# Transform table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table :

```
Code Article    PrixRevientHT   PrixRevientTTC  Date debut  Date fin
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
768180101   1,344   1,34    25/10/2015  07/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    29/10/2015  07/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    10/11/2015  07/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    11/11/2015  07/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    28/11/2015  07/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    08/12/2015  31/12/2015
768180101   1,344   1,34    01/01/2016  31/12/2049
783681833   1,593   1,59    10/10/2015  07/12/2015
783681833   1,593   1,59    11/11/2015  07/12/2015
783681833   1,593   1,59    08/12/2015  31/12/2015
783681833   1,593   1,59    01/01/2016  31/12/2049
```

Is there a way to get the following result

```
Code Article    PrixRevientHT   PrixRevientTTC  Date debut  Date fin
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
768180101   1,344   1,34    25/10/2015  31/12/2049
783681833   1,593   1,59    10/10/2015  31/12/2049
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and select minimum date debut and maximum date fin.

```
select code_article, prixrevientht, prixrevientttc, min(date_debut), max(date_fin)
from yourtable
group by code_article, prixrevientht, prixrevientttc
```